# Masking a raster using a shapefile with rasterio

Tags: python, shapefile, rasterio

This question refers to the doc of rasterio:
https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/masking-by-shapefile.html

I used the given code on the website.

```
out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "height": out_image.shape[1],
                 "width": out_image.shape[2],
                 "transform": out_transform})

with rasterio.open("RGB.byte.masked.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)
```

How do they create the RGB.byte.masked.tif file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line below opens `"RGB.byte.masked.tif"` for writing (note the `"w"` argument). It creates the file if it does not exist and completely overwrites it if it does exist.

```
with rasterio.open("RGB.byte.masked.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
```

Comment: Thanks! My shapefile has the coordinates: [[(0.0, 0.0),(0.0, 100.0),(100.0, 100.0),(100.0, 0.0),(0.0, 0.0)]] but the RGB.byte.masked.tif file at the end is the same as the RGB.byte.tif file at the beginning. I thought it would be a new file with the bounds equal to the shapefile ?

Comment: Yes, it should. But the coordinates `(0.0, 0.0),(0.0, 100.0),etc...` look wrong.